# Black color transformation with transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gimp, transparency, transform

I need to make an icon like this http://findicons.com/icon/download/579673/stackoverflow_24_black/24/ico?id=582600 so that it is in blue color (instead of black). I can't use Hue/Saturation/Curves because they do not transform black color. I can't also use fill tool because I need to preserve borders, which are partially black with some transparency. The preferred tool is GIMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for Gimp: in the Layers list, select the layer and click the *Alpha-lock* icon (checkerboard icon at the top of the Layers list). This prevents any modification of the opacity of the pixels.

Then bucket-fill the layer (no selection necessary) with any color you want:

[image]

Comment: Exact same procedure works for Photoshop.